# How to insert about 1 million rows to a MySQL db using node-mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm trying to build an app where there are two given lists - one of first-names and the other of last-names. I am trying to create a database with every combination of first-name and last-name. I'm generating the combinations and then trying to insert them into my database. But it seems that the memory is insufficient to handle this even though I have sliced my fullNames (firstname+lastname) array into smaller arrays.

```
// using the node-mysql driver to interact with mysql db
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '*******',
    database : '*******',
    multipleStatements: true,
});

var firstNames, lastNames; // arrays that will store
                           // first-names and last-names from files

function readFirstLastNames() {
    connection.connect();
    var fs = require("fs");
    firstNames = fs.readFileSync('firstnames.out').toString().split("\n");
    firstNames.sort();
    lastNames = fs.readFileSync('lastnames.out').toString().split("\n");
    lastNames.sort();
    connection.end();
}

/*
const f = firstNames; const l = lastNames;

genNames(firstNames,lastNames);

var allNames;

function genNames(fN, lN) {
    flatmap = (xs, fN) => xs.map(fN).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
    allNames = flatmap(fN, a => lN.map(b => `${a} ${b}`));
}
*/

function insertIntoDB(x, y) {
    connection.connect();
    var fullname_part = fullNames.slice(x, y);
    connection.query('INSERT INTO names (firstname, lastname) VALUES ?', [fullNames], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            return;
        }
    });
    console.log("Done inserting all combinations of names.");
    connection.end();
}

readFirstLastNames();

var fullNames = firstNames.reduce((pairs, first) => { lastNames.forEach(last => pairs.push([first, last])); return pairs; }, [])

var x = 1;
for (var y = 10000; y < 1000000;) {
    insertIntoDB(x, y);
    x = y;
    y = y + 10000;
}
```

But when I try to run - `node index.js`, I get the following errors:

```
Done inserting all combinations of names.
Done inserting all combinations of names.
Done inserting all combinations of names.
Done inserting all combinations of names.
Done inserting all combinations of names.

<--- Last few GCs --->

    7095 ms: Scavenge 1399.0 (1457.9) -> 1399.0 (1457.9) MB, 1.4 / 0 ms (+ 56.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
    7843 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.0 (1457.9) -> 1398.4 (1457.9) MB, 748.5 / 0 ms (+ 441.4 ms in 1126 steps since start of marking, biggest step 60.3 ms) [last resort gc].
    8585 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.4 (1457.9) -> 1398.4 (1457.9) MB, 741.2 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x3fc5864b4629 <JS Object>
    2: arrayToList [/Users/adas/Downloads/signzy/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:~58] [pc=0x3d90a7d8ead7] (this=0x233152605a09 <an Object with map 0x38dc0d04dcc1>,array=0x225c88bf01f1 <JS Array[881892]>,timeZone=0x2ed2ed0de679 <String[5]: local>)
    3: escape [/Users/adas/Downloads/signzy/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:~33] [pc=0x3d90a7d877e8] (this=0x233152605a09 <an Object w...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Abort trap: 6
```

I would like to understand how I may get past this issue and solve my problem! Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 1** : As per the comment below by @tadman, I have executed the following changes to my code so as to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

```
// using the node-mysql driver to interact with mysql db
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '******',
    database : '******',
    multipleStatements: true,
});

connection.connect();

var firstNames, lastNames; // arrays that will store
                           // first-names and last-names from files

function readFirstLastNames() { // reads firstnames.out and lastnames.out, puts them in arrays and sorts etc.
    var fs = require("fs");
    firstNames = fs.readFileSync('firstnames.out').toString().split("\n");
    lastNames = fs.readFileSync('lastnames.out').toString().split("\n");
}


readFirstLastNames();

var fullNames = firstNames.reduce((pairs, first) => { lastNames.forEach(last => pairs.push([first, last])); return pairs; }, []) // fullNames has all combinations of names.
fullNames.sort();


// Writing all combinations out to file in a comma separated syntax
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.createWriteStream('db_inserts.txt');
file.on('error', function(err) { /* error handling */ });
fullNames.forEach(function(v) { file.write(v.join(',') + '\n'); });
file.end();


// using node-mysql in conjunction with LOAD DATA INFILE to read the inserts into the table.
connection.query('LOAD DATA INFILE \'/Users/adas/Downloads/signzy/db_inserts.txt\' INTO TABLE names (firstname, lastname) FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'', (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
});
connection.end();
console.log("Done");
```

But now I see a different issue. It gives me a syntax error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', '' at line 1 .

**EDIT 2** : As pointed out by @tadman, the column name list should come at the end of the query. So changing the query to: `LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/adas/Downloads/signzy/db_inserts.txt' INTO TABLE names FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (firstname, lastname);` fixed the issue.

**SIDENOTE** : @tadman also pointed out that with Node, we don't need to force-use backslash to escape single-quotes. Simply surround the entire query with double-quotes and then go on to use single-quotes wherever required in between.

Comment: Generate a CSV and use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). This is actually considerably more efficient than ramming through X million queries. Additionally, try not to use the raw drivers in Node, instead use something like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) that gives you a little abstraction.

Comment: @tadman I was going to suggest this, too, but felt like writing out a node solution. OP: Doing file pre-processing and loading the whole file into the DB is a significantly superior solution.

Comment: @msanford Node can generate the file, command MySQL to load it, and follow up to test that it worked out. It's a Node solution.

Comment: @tadman Definitely.

Comment: @tadman, please take a look at my edit. I have executed your solution, but have a slightly different issue now.

Comment: Remember Node allows quoting with `"` and `'`' so if you have single quotes inside your string, use the other kind, and vice-versa. There's no reason to fight your own decision and have to backslash all your single quotes.

Comment: I think if you read the specification closely your column name list should come last.

Comment: @tadman, Haha, absolutely. This works - `LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/adas/Downloads/signzy/db_inserts.txt' INTO TABLE names FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (firstname, lastname)` .. inb4 me by a few seconds, at most! :) Thank you!

Comment: Add that on as an answer if you got it. Helps other people with the same problem, and other people might even be you in the future when you forgot how this worked.

Comment: @tadman, done. Thanks!

Comment: @tadman, the code behaves in a very unpredictable manner. It inserts a random number of rows to the table. It seems like the query doesn't start AFTER the file `db_inserts.txt` is populated. It seems the querying starts in between. Any suggestions on how I may fix this?

Comment: The #1 gotcha when writing Node code is that things are asynchronous and you'll need to ensure that your file is *completely written* before you attempt to load any data into MySQL. It's probably the case that Node is still working on writing data when you initiate the `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: How long did it take to complete the execution 1 M records?

Comment: I'd argue if your use case is to load millions of custom test rows of quality data into multiple tables, ultimately which will be queried in a fairly complex way, your main concern is the data mapping.  That's what will take ages.  Both in terms of how you think about mapping arrays per field with millions of elements, and the processing.  And frankly, at that point, I'd rather have something I can configure and walk away from.  Only to come back to everything loaded into my DB automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: As the thread has progressed, it's obvious that the way to go for this problem is to generate a file and load it into the database; I'll leave this answer here in case someone actually needs to do what I describe.

---

You're probably running out of memory because node-mysql's `.query()` method is, like most things in Node, asynchronous. So what you're actually doing is calling `insertIntoDB(x, y);` within the for loop and then instantly calling another one, not waiting for the first query to finish before trying another one, until you run out of memory.

I see that you're already including `async`. You can use something like [`async.mapSeries`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries) to serialize your `INSERT`s (given that your re-implement your `allNames` accumulator).

```
'use strict';
connection.connect();
async.mapSeries(allNames, (data, callback) => {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO names (firstname, lastname) VALUES ?', [data.firstName, data.firstName], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error: ' + err.stack);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, result);
        }
    });
}, (err, results) => {
    // Final callback
    if (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
});
connection.end();
```

Additionally:

1. Sort your file *once* and write it back to disk so you don't have to sort it every time you load it.
2. Remove additional calls to `connection.connect()` and `.end()`: just connect once at the start of your batch, or the whole script.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I had accepted your answer. Though @tadmans approach is more efficient, you answered the original question. Thank you for taking the time to write this answer! :)

Comment: @0x23212f No problem, and my pleasure.